# REMOVE GNS3 1.3.9

Tags: server, application-development, uninstall

This version keeps giving this error message "

> Can't connect to server http://127.0.0.1:8002

Even when I change the port number.

I am wondering how can I uninstall it since I compiled using the commands from [GNS3 community site](https://community.gns3.com/message/15024#15024).

How can I remove from my machine. since

```
sudo apt-get remove gns3
```

doesn't work.

Comment: you cant `apt-get` for compiled software. you need to find and delete it.  For the connection issue, have you check firewall on Ubuntu (UFW)?

Answer (score 2):

I have no desire to create an account to download the source code. Therefore, a basic procedure.

You can't remove a compiled version in the same way as a deb package.

1. If you no longer have the source code, download the source code again
2. Go into the source folder and start

   ```
   sudo make uninstall
   ```

If there is no `uninstall` rule, folow the next steps

1. Install `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
2. Go into the source folder and install, **yes install** via

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   Why? `checkinstall` creates a deb package and installs the package and overwrites in this way all installed files of your earlier installation via `sudo make install`
3. Remove

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ...
   ```

   The package name is shown after `checkinstall` finished

In the future, use `checkinstall` to install your self-compiled code.

More steps

1. Search the `cp` commands in the installation guide and remove the targets, e.g.

   ```
   sudo cp libiniparser.* /usr/lib/
   ```

   Therefore

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/lib/libiniparser.*
   ```
2. Nevertheless, you will retain remainders in your system. But you could have a look at the content of the `setup.py` files of *GNS3 GUI* and *GNS3 Server*.

Comment: Accepted and un-accepted, why?